# Javascript find closest number in array without going over

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I modify this very nice function to find the closest number but never higher than the input?

```
function closest(arr, closestTo){

var closest = Math.max.apply(null, arr);

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] >= closestTo && arr[i] < closest) closest = arr[i];
}

return closest;
}

console.log(closest(myArray, 1234));
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could remove the part that checks for greater.
Another method would be: remove higher values, and get max from remaining ones:

```
function closest(arr,val){
    return Math.max.apply(null, arr.filter(function(v){return v <= val}))
}

console.log(closest([1,22,121223],24)) // prints 22
```

Comment: @m-el-set but you need to make sure that the given input is not smaller that all the elements in the array. So if arr = [30,40,50] you will have an exception if you call closest(arr, 10)

Comment: @HoumamWazzeh actually, it will return -Infinity. Yeah, behavious for not finding any element should be added

Answer (score 0):

remove the `greater than` comparator:

```
if(arr[i] == closestTo && arr[i] < closest) closest = arr[i];
```